# Number of zeros at the end of $5^5 \times 10^{10} \times 15^{15} \times \dots \times 120^{120} \times 125^{125} $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find the number of zeros at the end of the number
$$5^5 \times 10^{10} \times 15^{15} \times \dots \times 120^{120} \times 125^{125} $$

So, First I know that the zeros are formed by the multiplication of 2 with 5 and 2 appears less number of times than 5 than we should count the number of 2.
Even though I can count the number of 2 manually be selecting each even terms in the product and calculating the power of 2 in that and adding all such.

**But, What if the product was large that it would consume more time doing this way?**, so I searched I find that it is solved as follows:

> Highest power of 2 in the given product = (Number of multiples of 2) + (Number of multiples of 4) + (Number of multiples of 8) + (Number of multiples of 16)
> = (10+20+30+...+120) + (20+40+60+...+120) + (40+80+120) + 80 = 1520

**How** did they calculate it like that?

Comment: Which part of the calculation are you unclear? Which equality?

Comment: I'm assuming they did a similar calculation of the highest power of $5$?

Comment: This part of the video by zetamath on [counting how many times a prime $p$ divides $n!$](https://youtu.be/oVaSA_b938U?si=5Skhu_rOB25io_T6&t=476) explains it very well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking. Do you understand why the are finding the highest power of 2? Do you understand what they mean by the numbers of multiples of 2,4, etc? and why?  Do you understand that 10+20+30+...+120 is supposed to be the number of $2$s?  Do you understand why?

Comment: @fleablood I did not understand that why they calculated separately the multiples of $2, 2^2$ and so on, and yes I agree why the $10+20+... +120$ are the number of 2's. Also I am not sure that counting how many times a prime p divides n! can be used for any n, because not every n can be a factorial of a natural number.

Comment: They did it because they could.  And it works.  We know that ever even base will yield a 2 and some of them will yield 4 and if you are like me you probably figured wed count them in order: $10$ is one two and $20$ gives us two more so three twos so far and $30$ give us one so 4 and $40$ is div by 8 so that is 3 more so 7 and... we soon  realize we are going to lose track.  The big *AHA* moment is realizing we can to just all the first 2s first for all the even numbers and then go back to get the second twos from the multiples of 4 and so on.  So for say $100!$ we have 50 evens, 25, 12, etc.

Comment: This is a different question from what is the largest power of $2$ that can divide $120!$ because it is asking a different thing.  But the spirit and the "trick" and the "aha" moment are exactly the same.  Get a 2 for the 10,20,30,40, etc.  Then you go back and get a second 2 from every other one that was a multiple of 4.  Then you go back and get a third 2 from every fourth one that was a multiple of 8.  You are doing differen things and the powers add a twist.  But the concept and problem solving is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "How did they calculate it like that?"

For $~p~$ prime, and $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ let $~V_p(n)~$ denote the largest integer $~\alpha~$ such that $~p^\alpha ~| ~n.~$  This implies that $~p^{\alpha + 1}~$ does not divide $~n.$

Now, let $~S = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k\}$ be any set of $~k~$ positive integers, and suppose that you wanted to compute $~V_p\left[\prod_{i=1}^k x_i\right].$

The basic approach would be, that for any $~r \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you would let $~S_r~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that contains all elements $~x_i~$ (and only those elements) such that $~V_p(x_i) = r.~$

Let $~|S_r|~$ denote the number of elements in $~S_r.$

Then,

$$V_p\left[\prod_{i=1}^k x_i\right] \\
= [1 \times |S_1|] + [2 \times |S_2|] + [3 \times |S_3|] + \cdots \\
= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \left[ ~r \times |S_r| \right]. \tag1 $$

The computation in (1) above can be re-expressed as

```
  |S_1|
+ |S_2| + |S_2|
+ |S_3| + |S_3| + |S_3|
+ |S_4| + |S_4| + |S_4| + |S_4|
+ ...
```

In the above *tableau*,

- the 1st column represents all multiples of $~p^1.$
- the 2nd column represents all multiples of $~p^2.$
- the 3rd column represents all multiples of $~p^3.$
- the 4th column represents all multiples of $~p^4.$
- $\cdots$

Comment: Could you please tell more why you took $r \times |S_r|$ instead of $|S_r|$ in the  sum?

Comment: @mat09 Easiest to see by example.  Let $~p = 5,~$ let $~S = \{5,10,25,50,75,125,250,375,500\},~$ and assume that you wanted to calculate $$V_5 \left[ ~\prod_{x\in S} x ~\right].$$  Then $~S_1 = \{5,10\}, ~S_2 = \{25,50,75\},~$ and $~S_3 = \{125,250,375,500\}.~$  Then, $$ ~V_5 \left[ ~\prod_{x\in S} x ~\right] = (1 \times 2) + (2 \times 3) + (3 \times 4).$$

Answer (score 1):

To know how many trailing zeros there are we must figure out the highest power of $10$ that divides the number (that power is how many zeros there are).  To find the highest power of $10$ that divides the number we must find out the highest power of $2$ that divides the number and the highest power of $5$ and compare them.  (Take the lower of the powers, each power of one combines with a power of the other to make a power of $10$ and you'll have as many powers of $10$ as lower of those to powers).  This part of the argument is about figuring out the power of $2$ that divides the number.

The powers of two come from each even component.  $10^{10}, 20^{20}, 30^{30}$ etc.

The even components are $10^{10}, 20^{20}, 30^{30}, ...., 110^{110}, 120^{120}$.

As these can be written as $(2\times 5)^{10} = 2^{10}\times 5^{10}, (2\times 10)^{20}= 2^{20}\times 10^{20}, (2\times 15)^{30}=2^{30}\times 15^{30}$, we get that $2^{10}, 2^{20}, 2^{30}, .... , 120^{120}=2^{120}\times 60^{120}$

Thus we have extract $2^{10}\times 2^{20}\times 2^{30}\times ...... 2^{120}= 2^{10+20+30+....+120}$ as a power of $2$ component.

But we are not done.  We have extacted *one* two from the even components.  But some components weren't just even, they were divisible by $4$ or by $8$ or by $16$ etc.  We've only extract *one* $2$ from them but they have terms left.

When we looked at the even components $10^{10}, 20^{20}, 30^{30},.... , 100^{100}, 110^{110}, 120^{120}$ and extracted $2^{10}, 2^{20},...., 2^{120}$ we left behind $5^{10}, 10^{20}, 15^{30}, 20^{40},...., 50^{100}, 55^{120}, 60^{120}$ and some of those are even and we can extract powers of $2$ from those.  These terms were the terms that were originally multiples of $4$.

We can extract $2^{20}, 2^{40}, 2^{60},.... 2^{120}$ from these to get $2^{20+40+60+....+120}$ to get the powers of $2$ extracted from the multiples of $4$.  Combine these with the first $2^{10+20+30+....+120}$ we get $2^{10+20+30+.... + 110+120}\times 2^{20+40+60+.... + 100 + 120}=2^{(10+20+30+.... + 110+120) + (20+40+60+.... +100+120)}$.

But we still aren't done.  We left behind $5^{20}, 10^{40},15^{60}, 20^{80}, 25^{100}, 30^{120}$ and from $10^{40}, 20^{80}, 30^{120}$ (these come from the terms that originally were multiples of $8$) we can get $2^{40+80+120}$.  Combine with what we had we get $2^{(10+20+30+.... + 110+120) + (20+40+60+.... +100+120) + (40 + 80+120)}$

But we still aren't done.  We left behind $5^4, 10^{80},$ and $15^{120}$.  From this the $10^{80}$ is still even (it was originally $80^{80}$ and was divisible by $16$).  From this we get $2^{80}\times 5^{80}$ and we can extract $2^{80}$.

Combine it with what we had and we get $2^{(10+20+30+.... + 110+120) + (20+40+60+.... +100+120) + (40 + 80+120)+80}$.

And now we are done.  We have no even components left.  Had the series gone on to $160^{160} = (32 \times 5)^{160}$ we'd have another step to do but we are done.

The highest power of $2$ that divides our number is $2^{1520}$.

Now we have to compare to the highest power of $5$ which we can find similarly.  ... Or maybe the proof assumed it was obvious there were more powers of $5$ than of $2$ (I don't want to get into that now).  If we did the same thing but with $5$ we'd get that $5^{2125}$ is the highest power of $5$.  So $1520$ of the $2$ combine with $1520$ of the powers of $5$ to get $1520$ powers of $10$.

There are $1520$ zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the number as a product to try to understand this better: $\prod_{x=1}^{25} 5x^{5x}$

As you already stated, zeros are formed when $5$ and $2$ and multiplied.

$20+60+80+100+240+240+10^{10+20+30+\dots+120} = 1520$

Since 2's and 5's form 0's, we know there are more 5's than 2's so we can just find the multiples of 2's.

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptjRiGEuRCM) for more. (Hindi) :(